# How to add sentence number in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

I would like to add sentence number to a text file: 
Put [1][2][3]... in front of each sentence.

```
[1] Sentence one. [2] Sentence two. ...
```

And a sentence ended with one of `.!?`.

I have no clue how to do it in `Clojure.` Here is my attempt:

```
(def text "Martin Luther King, Jr.

I Have a Dream

delivered 28 August 1963, at the Lincoln Memorial, Washington D.C.


I am happy to join with you today in what will go down in history as the greatest demonstration for freedom in the history of our nation.

Five score years ago, a great American, in whose symbolic shadow we stand today, signed the Emancipation Proclamation. This momentous decree came as a great beacon light of hope to millions of Negro slaves who had been seared in the flames of withering injustice. It came as a joyous daybreak to end the long night of their captivity.

But one hundred years later, the Negro still is not free. One hundred years later, the life of the Negro is still sadly crippled by the manacles of segregation and the chains of discrimination. One hundred years later, the Negro lives on a lonely island of poverty in the midst of a vast ocean of material prosperity. One hundred years later, the Negro is still languished in the corners of American society and finds himself an exile in his own land. And so we've come here today to dramatize a shameful condition.")
```

Define sentence ending:

```
(def sentence-ending #"[.!?]")
```

Use replace function:

```
(require '[clojure.string :as str])
(str/replace text sentence-ending "[number]")
```

I know this is logically wrong! I got replace all the `.!?` with a string. Perhaps string replace is not the right way. How to tackle this problem?

Answer (score 3):

You can split the `text` into sequence of sentences. Then `map` each sentence to prepend `[number]`, and join the sentences again to make one string.

```
(->> (clojure.string/split text #"[.?!]")       ; split text
     (map-indexed #(str "[" (inc %1) "] " %2))  ; prepend number
     (apply str))                               ; join to one string
```

But the condition for splitting the text into string is naive. As you can see, some of words contains `.` which are not the end of sentence. You should refine the sentence termination condition.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I don't mean to replace all the `.!? `. My poor origin program was wrong. I put the replacement  expression because I was stucked there.

Answer (score 0):

One way to get the full sentence (including the punctuation) is to regex out the whole thing and use a matcher. I don't know if this is the best way. But it works.

After that, I think interleave works nicely for this kind of problem.

```
(let [matcher (re-matcher #"[^.!?]*[.!?]" text)
      sentences (take-while seq (repeatedly #(re-find matcher)))
      numbers (map #(str "[" % "] ") (range))]
  (apply str (interleave numbers sentences)))
```

Comment: Your approach is brilliant! Since the text file I'm processing with line ending `\r\n`. I added this to the `re-matcher`: `#"[^.!?]*[.!?][ \r\n]*"`. But I can't figure out how to deal with: 1. abbreviation like `Washington D.C.` 2. sentence after a colon and a new line character (`:\r\n`) should be a new sentence. Is there any hint to handle this? I'm a beginner in programming, so my question might be naive or trivial. Thank you for your answer - it's enlightening.